# Does hashtables support the same methods as binary search trees?

Tags: methods, binary-search-tree, hashtable

Out of curiosity, are there any methods that Binary Search Tree support that Hashtables doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

There are several operations relating to ordering that binary search trees support easily and efficiently that hash tables don't. For example:

- Finding the smallest key greater than some value, or the greatest key smaller than some value
- Finding all of the keys between two given values
- Visiting all of the elements, or all of the elements between two values, in order